# How to implement "next" for a dictionary object to be iterable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iterator, iterable

I've got the following wrapper for a dictionary:

```
class MyDict:
    def __init__(self):
        self.container = {}

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.container[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return self.container[key]

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        pass

dic = MyDict()
dic['a'] = 1
dic['b'] = 2

for key in dic:
    print key
```

My problem is that I don't know how to implement the `next` method to make `MyDict` iterable. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Dictionaries are themselves not an *iterator* (which can only be iterated over *once*). You usually make them an *iterable*, an object for which you can produce multiple *iterators* instead.

Drop the `next` method altogether, and have `__iter__` return an iterable object each time it is called. That can be as simple as just returning an iterator for `self.container`:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.container)
```

If you *must* make your class an iterator, you'll have to somehow track a current iteration position and raise `StopIteration` once you reach the 'end'. A naive implementation could be to store the `iter(self.container)` object on `self` the first time `__iter__` is called:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self):
    if not hasattr(self, '_iter'):
        self._iter = iter(self.container)
    return next(self._iter)
```

at which point the `iter(self.container)` object takes care of tracking iteration position for you, and will raise `StopIteration` when the end is reached. It'll also raise an exception if the underlying dictionary was altered (had keys added or deleted) and iteration order has been broken.

Another way to do this would be to just store in integer position and index into `list(self.container)` each time, and simply ignore the fact that insertion or deletion can alter the iteration order of a dictionary:

```
_iter_index = 0

def __iter__(self):
    return self

def next(self):
    idx = self._iter_index
    if idx is None or idx >= len(self.container):
        # once we reach the end, all iteration is done, end of.
        self._iter_index = None
        raise StopIteration()
    value = list(self.container)[idx]
    self._iter_index = idx + 1
    return value
```

In both cases your object is then an *iterator* that can only be iterated over *once*. Once you reach the end, you can't restart it again.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to be able to use your dict-like object inside nested loops, for example, or any other application that requires multiple iterations over the same object, then you need to implement an `__iter__` method that returns a newly-created iterator object.

Python's iterable objects all do this:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3].__iter__()
<listiterator object at 0x7f67146e53d0>
>>> iter([1, 2, 3]) # A simpler equivalent
<listiterator object at 0x7f67146e5390>
```

The simplest thing for your objects' `__iter__` method to do would be to return an iterator on the underlying dict, like this:

```
def __iter__(self):
    return iter(self.container)
```

For more detail than you probably will ever require, see [this Github repository](https://github.com/steveholden/iteration).